# building minimal piece of assembly code produces empty binary file

Tags: assembly, linker, arm, elf, bin

I'm trying to build a minimal startup code for my MCU (tms570lc4357zwt, ARM Cortex-R5f), but when I build it and convert it to binary format, the size of the produced **.bin** file is 0.

The structure of test files is:

```
test
  +--CMakeLists.txt
  +--gnu.cmake
  +--isr.S
  +--linker.ld
```

The version of the tools I use are:

- arm-none-eabi-gcc: 8-2018-q4-major
- cmake: 3.15.2

Here is my minimal piece of assembly code (isr.S):

```
.arm

.global isr_vector
.global bootloader

.section .flash_code_isr_vector
isr_vector:
    LDR     pc, = bootloader /* reset. */
    LDR     pc, = 0x08000004 /* undefined instruction. */
    LDR     pc, = 0x08000008 /* system call. */
    LDR     pc, = 0x0800000C /* prefetch abort. */
    LDR     pc, = 0x08000010 /* data abort. */
    LDR     pc, = 0x08000014 /* reserved. */
    LDR     pc, = 0x08000018 /* IRQ. */
    LDR     pc, = 0x0800001C /* FIQ. */

.section .flash_code_bootloader
bootloader:
    B       .
```

and I use the following linker script (linker.ld):

```
MEMORY
{
    FLASH_TCM (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 4M
    RAM_TCM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x08000000, LENGTH = 512K
    RAM_ECC (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x08400000, LENGTH = 512K
}

ENTRY(isr_vector)

SECTIONS
{
    .flash_code_isr_vector 0x00000000 :
    {
        KEEP(*(.flash_code_isr_vector))
    } > FLASH_TCM

    .flash_code_bootloader 0x00000100 :
    {
        *(.flash_code_bootloader)
    } > FLASH_TCM
}
```

Bellow, the toolchain file (gnu.cmake) and the cmake file (CMakeLists.txt) I use to build it:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM BOTH)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS TRUE)

set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)

find_program(ASM_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
find_program(C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
find_program(LINKER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
find_program(ARCHIVER arm-none-eabi-ar)
find_program(RANLIB arm-none-eabi-ranlib)

set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER ${ASM_COMPILER})
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${C_COMPILER})
set(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE ${LINKER})
set(CMAKE_AR ${ARCHIVER})
set(CMAKE_RANLIB ${RANLIB})

add_compile_options(-mbig-endian
    -march=armv7-r
    -Wall
    -Wextra)

add_link_options(-mbig-endian
    -nostdlib
    -Wall
    -Wextra)
```

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(test VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES ASM)

add_executable(isr.elf isr.S)
add_compile_options(isr.elf PRIVATE -O0 -g)
set_target_properties(isr.elf PROPERTIES
    LINK_FLAGS "-T ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/linker.ld")

add_custom_target(isr.bin
    DEPENDS isr.elf
    COMMAND arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary isr.elf isr.bin
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})

add_custom_target(isr.asm
    DEPENDS isr.elf
    COMMAND arm-none-eabi-objdump -D isr.elf > isr.asm
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})

add_custom_target(isr.size
    DEPENDS isr.elf
    COMMAND arm-none-eabi-size isr.elf -A -t -x
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY})
```

The issue can be reproduced by running (in the folder containing all files) `mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../gnu.cmake`

Now comes the issue:
When I ask the size of the **.elf** (invoking the `isr.size` taget), I get

```
isr.elf  :
section                  size    addr
.flash_code_isr_vector   0x40     0x0
.flash_code_bootloader    0x4   0x100
.ARM.attributes          0x1d     0x0
Total                    0x61
```

which seems reasonable. now when I produce the **.bin** file (invoking the `isr.bin` target), the produced file size is 0. Does anyone have an idea why? Because when I disassemble the **.elf** file (invoking the `isr.asm` target), the generated assembly code seems correct:

```
isr.elf:     file format elf32-bigarm


Disassembly of section .flash_code_isr_vector:

00000000 <isr_vector>:
   0:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 20 <isr_vector+0x20>
   4:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 24 <isr_vector+0x24>
   8:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 28 <isr_vector+0x28>
   c:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 2c <isr_vector+0x2c>
  10:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 30 <isr_vector+0x30>
  14:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 34 <isr_vector+0x34>
  18:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 38 <isr_vector+0x38>
  1c:   e59ff018    ldr pc, [pc, #24]   ; 3c <isr_vector+0x3c>
  20:   00000100    andeq   r0, r0, r0, lsl #2
  24:   08000004    stmdaeq r0, {r2}
  28:   08000008    stmdaeq r0, {r3}
  2c:   0800000c    stmdaeq r0, {r2, r3}
  30:   08000010    stmdaeq r0, {r4}
  34:   08000014    stmdaeq r0, {r2, r4}
  38:   08000018    stmdaeq r0, {r3, r4}
  3c:   0800001c    stmdaeq r0, {r2, r3, r4}

Disassembly of section .flash_code_bootloader:

00000100 <bootloader>:
 100:   eafffffe    b   100 <bootloader>

Disassembly of section .ARM.attributes:

00000000 <.ARM.attributes>:
   0:   41000000    mrsmi   r0, (UNDEF: 0)
   4:   1c616561    cfstr64ne   mvdx6, [r1], #-388  ; 0xfffffe7c
   8:   62690001    rsbvs   r0, r9, #1, 0
   c:   00000012    andeq   r0, r0, r2, lsl r0
  10:   05372d52    ldreq   r2, [r7, #-3410]!   ; 0xfffff2ae
  14:   00060a07    andeq   r0, r6, r7, lsl #20
  18:   52080109    andpl   r0, r8, #1073741826 ; 0x40000002
  1c:   Address 0x000000000000001c is out of bounds.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your assembly code you haven't marked your sections as allocatable so they aren't being output when you produce the binary file. If you had dumped the header files with

```
arm-none-eabi-objdump -x isr.elf
```

The output would have looked similar to:

> ```
> isr.elf:     file format elf32-bigarm
> isr.elf
> architecture: arm, flags 0x00000012:
> EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS
> start address 0x00000000
> private flags = 5000200: [Version5 EABI] [soft-float ABI]
>
> Sections:
> Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
>   0 .flash_code_isr_vector 00000040  00000000  00000000  00000034  2**2
>                   CONTENTS, READONLY
>   1 .flash_code_bootloadery 00000004  00000000  00000000  00000074  2**2
>                   CONTENTS, READONLY
>   2 .ARM.attributes 0000001d  00000000  00000000  00000078  2**0
>                   CONTENTS, READONLY
> ```

The flags are only `CONTENTS` and `READONLY`. It is missing the `ALLOC` (allocatable) flag. Since your sections appear to also be code I'd consider modifying `isr.S` by adding `"ax"` attributes with something like:

```
.arm

.global isr_vector
.global bootloader

.section .flash_code_isr_vector,"ax",%progbits
isr_vector:
    LDR     pc, = bootloader /* reset. */
    LDR     pc, = 0x08000004 /* undefined instruction. */
    LDR     pc, = 0x08000008 /* system call. */
    LDR     pc, = 0x0800000C /* prefetch abort. */
    LDR     pc, = 0x08000010 /* data abort. */
    LDR     pc, = 0x08000014 /* reserved. */
    LDR     pc, = 0x08000018 /* IRQ. */
    LDR     pc, = 0x0800001C /* FIQ. */

.section .flash_code_bootloader,"ax",%progbits
bootloader:
    B       .
```

If you rebuild the code the `bin` file should be non-zero and the ELF headers should now look something like:

> ```
> Sections:
> Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
>   0 .flash_code_isr_vector 00000040  00000000  00000000  00010000  2**2
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
>   1 .flash_code_bootloader 00000004  00000100  00000100  00010100  2**2
>                   CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
>   2 .ARM.attributes 0000001d  00000000  00000000  00010104  2**0
>                   CONTENTS, READONLY
> ```

---

The `.section` directive is [documented for ELF](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Section.html) as:

> ELF Version
>
> This is one of the ELF section stack manipulation
>   directives. The others are .subsection (see SubSection), .pushsection
>   (see PushSection), .popsection (see PopSection), and .previous (see
>   Previous).
>
> For ELF targets, the .section directive is used like this:
>
> ```
> .section name [, "flags"[, @type[,flag_specific_arguments]]]
> ```
>
> [snip]
>
> a section is allocatable
>
> d section is a GNU_MBIND section
>
> e section is excluded from executable and shared library.
>
> w section is writable
>
> x section is executable
>
> M section is mergeable
>
> S section contains zero terminated strings
>
> G section is a member of a section group
>
> T section is used for thread-local-storage
>
> ? section is a member of the previously-current section’s group, if
>   any
>
> [snip]
>
> The optional type argument may contain one of the following constants:
>
> @progbits section contains data
>
> @nobits section does not contain data (i.e., section only occupies
>   space)
>
> [snip]
>
> Note on targets where the @ character is the start of a comment (eg
>   ARM) then another character is used instead. For example the ARM port
>   uses the % character.